# Understanding the authorization part of JWT and session

Tags: session, microservices, jwt

So i read about how authentication is done using JWT, where we basically verify if the token is valid using a private key (assuming RSA is the algortihm). And if the token is valid, then the user is considered authenticated. 
 
 And I also read about session authentication where we check if the user supplied session id (through cookie), exist in the session store (assuming mysql / redis is used to store session). If it exist, then the user is considered authenticated.

But how do we use JWT and session for authorization ? Lets consider an action such as `GET invoice` , whereby a user can only view the invoice that he owns.

If we consider the user is already authenticated,

how do we check if the user is authorized if we are using JWT?

And how do we do it for session ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing the things. One of the benefits using JWT is to avoid maintaining sessions which is big bottle neck in scaling.

JWT (Json Web Token) carry all the information that would require it to get authenticated, you don't need to maintain the session. Every single HTTP request to server will carry JWT that would contain necessary user claims including the signature. On server you will validate the signature to verify if the token is valid or not. You can verify the token without maintaining any session and there are number of ways to do it.

Since JWT is essentially a Json object (Header, Body , Signature) , you can put in claims (emails, roles, profile etc) in JWT body. Once you verify the token , you can extract the claims including any roles and check if user is authorized to access the resource.

You must look into Open ID Connect and Tokens [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens)